# Electron + Nuxt + Bootstrap-vue: Getting blank screen and error: Cannot find module 'vue' on running prod

Tags: electron, nuxt.js, bootstrap-vue, electron-builder

I created project using https://github.com/michalzaq12/electron-nuxt/tree/master/template

And for UI, I used Bootstrap-vue.

When I am running dev mode (yarn dev), it's working well with some warnings.

But when I run prod (built result), I am getting blank screen and following error.

[image]

I think the bootstrap-vue is the reason of this issue, but can't find out solution.

Please help me.